# Possible JDK bug in System.console()

Tags: java

The following code come from `java.lang.System.console()` method:

```
private static volatile Console cons = null;

/**
 * Returns the unique {@link java.io.Console Console} object associated
 * with the current Java virtual machine, if any.
 *
 * @return  The system console, if any, otherwise <tt>null</tt>.
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
 public static Console console() {
     if (cons == null) {
         synchronized (System.class) {
             cons = sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOAccess().console();
         }
     }
     return cons;
 }
```

In my opinion, these is a bug in this method. 
We should write it like this:

```
public static Console console() {
     if (cons == null) {
         synchronized (System.class) {
            if (cons == null)
                 cons = sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOAccess().console();
         }
     }
     return cons;
 }
```

Am I right? What's your opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/Console.java#538) of `JavaIOAccess`, you will find that there's a null-check inside it:

```
public Console console() {
    if (istty()) {
        if (cons == null)
            cons = new Console();
            return cons;
        }
    return null;
}
```

As this method is the only way to initialize that variable, then it's not a problem that the nested null check resides in another method. It's still impossible to get two distinct `Console` objects.

Comment: JavaIoAccess is only an interface. Implementations of console()  may vary.

Comment: They aren't. It's internal JDK code and internal JDK interface. In JDK there's only one implementation. If you try to replace it with your own implementation, then you are using Java in non-documented way, thus nothing will be guaranteed. Anyways you will not be able to create new `Console` object as `Console` class is final and has only private constructor. Of course you can play with reflection to access private constructor or use another ways to shoot your leg, but saying that something impossible I mean "impossible if you are using Java in documented way"

Comment: I see. Noted! I assumed it may change depending on the java version. But that is beyond this scope

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer got me deep into the implementation of JavaIOAccess and I think you are right. Variable cons is static :    private static Console cons; and synchronized (System.class) guarantee that there is only one way and one time initialization of cons.

Answer (score 4):

It is not. You can assign a value to it and it already has been initialized. I think the null check is redundant, it is already being checked outside and as [Tagir Valeev suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118182/4807777) , inside the JavaIoAccess implementation of console.

You may be thinking about thread contention and because the initialization is happening inside the synchronize block, multiple threads accessing it at the same time will trigger the redundant re-initialization.

So you can say it could be more of an improvement to reduce overhead rather than a bug.

However you should read more on [Double checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) , it contains exactly your scenario. Details below

---

It's interesting to see the subtle problems of using it in J2SE 1.4 (and earlier versions) with various compilers.

After J2SE 5.0 those problem have been fixed

> The volatile keyword now ensures that multiple threads handle the
>   singleton instance correctly.

As you will notice the Console static object is volatile.

By using the implementation as described in the above link:

```
private static volatile Console cons = null;
public static Console console() {
    Console result = console;
    if (result == null) {
        synchronized (System.class) {
            result = console;
            if (result == null) {
                console = result =sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOAccess().console();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could get such a performance improvement:

> Note the local variable result, which seems unnecessary. This ensures
>   that in cases where ***console*** is already initialized (i.e., most of the
>   time), the volatile field is only accessed once (due to "return
>   result;" instead of "return ***console***;"), which can improve the method's
>   overall performance by as much as 25 percent   -  *note: replaced helper with console for clarity*

But i am not sure how often console() is called from multiple-threads the first time - after that, the initialization is no longer a problem because of the outter null check.

This solution also creates overhead so the actual performance gain is debatable. Thus your suggestion (as adopted above) can be considered at best an improvement.

Comment: I'm very happy that I have learned the skill using a local variable result to improve the method's performance. Thank you again.